# Application Deployed Successful on GlassFish 4.1 but browsing error 404

Tags: java, spring-mvc, glassfish, netbeans-8

I am new to java spring and glassfish 4.1 .. my application is deploying successful in glassfish but browsing error 404 ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">


    <servlet>

    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>

    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

  </servlet> 
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping> 
    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>
      index.jsp
    </welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list> 
</web-app>
```

Comment: Try to use admin console, then Applications -> your application and check what context is it deployed in.

Comment: I have tried Admin console and also launched from there but same error

Comment: What is exact url you use?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/springapp/

Comment: Then I bet your url-pattern does not match that URL

Comment: I have added my web.xml code in my question and url-pattern is there

Comment: Does it match your URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
```

to

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

or use URL for the specific html file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add url-pattern
"*.xhtm"
if you work with xhtml files or
"*.jsf"
in jsf case.